# Weird output with Java String .matches()

Tags: java, regex

User inputs the following into scanner:

> "a " (character 'a' followed by a single space)

I understand why this works:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(in.nextLine().matches("a\\s"));
```

But I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(in.next().matches("a\\s"));
```

The first block of code (the one on top) returns `true` while the second one (bottom) returns `false`

The only difference between the two is one is using `nextLine()` and the other `next()`

Can anyone explain this behavior? I know best practices dictates to user Pattern and Matcher class but this is really bothering me.

I've also tried `("a(\\s)")`but this unfortunately gave me the same results. And I recall reading that `.matches()` method appends a `^` at the beginning of the input and a `$` at the end, but this should still not make it return false and I have tried it out and it did return false.

Comment: `Scanner.next()` will only read `a` without the space. So it cannot match the regex.

Comment: Yeah, unless you change your scanner's delimiter, `next()` reads _up to but not including_ the next whitespace character.

Comment: You guys are amazing. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the method `next()` it will only scan for one character of the file. Therefore `in.next()` would return `a` , `\` , `\` , and then `s` . By using `nextLine()` you are scanning the entire line and thus `a\\s`. Hope this helped!

Comment: Very much so! Thank you!

Comment: Minor correction, but `next()` would return `a` and then `(space)`. The regex itself is `a\\s`, but the input is `a(space)`. Same for `nextLine()`, it would return `a(space)`.